# DD-MMM-YYYY date format possible for input

Tags: input, date-format, orbeon, xforms

is a `DD-MMM-YYYY` (17-Oct-2012) date format possible for input?

I have tried to add below property in properties-local.xml for Input Date field.

`<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date" value="[D01]-[MNn,*-3]-[Y0001]"/>`

Date field is coming as : 17-10-2012 after selecting date from calendar.

For xforms:output, same `[D01]-[MNn,*-3]-[Y0001]` is displaying : 17-Oct-2012

Please suggest. Is this `[D01]-[MNn,*-3]-[Y0001]` format acceptable for oxf.xforms.format.input.date?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a property for input, do the following which might help you.

use `xxf:format` attribute for input control and use `format-date` function to get the expected format after selecting the date picker.

> ex:-

xxf:format = format-date(.,'[D01]-[MNn,*-3]-[Y]')

Regards,
Arjun